# Random moving of image and Hyperlink from one location to another using JavaScript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to sort of display predefined images say 5 images and its position needs to be changed randomly every user refreshes the web page that is Html based.

I need to do the same using JavaScript.

Also I need to change the hyperlink and image name associated with each and every image!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that could help us with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of image objects and the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

http://jsfiddle.net/zJhQG/

Comment: thnx ioneyed ,will  try it and also like to know whether same will be applicable for hyperlink also ?

Comment: @hero123: You can use it for whatever you need, I assumed you needed images to have a link corresponding to them - notice when you click on the numbers they go out to other sites. Just manipulate the array of objects - if you do not need an object (ie, just moving links or just images) then use an array with imageArray[idx] in the loop.

Comment: one more favour,have tried not not getting the solution as stated by you ,so can u provide me with the code